# react tinymce hpw to show only preview and print under file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm trying to create an application. Where I'm using tinymce as editor. In the file panel, I don;t want to show new document. Corrently it's rendering:

[image]

But I just want to render it with thse two options:

[image]

Can anyone help me with it?

Here is my related config:

```
plugins: 'print preview ...',
menubar: 'file edit ...',
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation if you want to control what you see on each discrete menu you have to provide those choices explicitly:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menu

The defaults are:

```
menu: {
    file: { title: 'File', items: 'newdocument restoredraft | preview | print ' },
    edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall | searchreplace' },
    view: { title: 'View', items: 'code | visualaid visualchars visualblocks | spellchecker | preview fullscreen' },
    insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'image link media template codesample inserttable | charmap emoticons hr | pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc | insertdatetime' },
    format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript codeformat | formats blockformats fontformats fontsizes align lineheight | forecolor backcolor | removeformat' },
    tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker spellcheckerlanguage | code wordcount' },
    table: { title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable | cell row column | tableprops deletetable' },
    help: { title: 'Help', items: 'help' }
  }
```

So if you only want 2 items on the file menu you would have to state that explicitly within the broader menu option:

```
file: { title: 'File', items: 'preview | print ' },
```

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle showing this in action:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/hYhaab